# axios get data not displaying in vuejs template v-for list

Tags: vue.js, axios

VueDev tools shows that axios get is returning a data array, but I cannot get the data to display. (Obviously I am a newbie)
Am I missing a step?

```
<template>
    <div  >
        <ul>
            <li v-for="dilo_role in dilo_roles"> {{ dilo_role.role }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                dilo_roles: []
            }
        },

        // Fetches roles when the component is created.

        mounted(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/dilo_roles')
                .then( response => this.dilo_roles = response.data );
        }

    }
</script>
```

Here's what axios response.data is getting:

```
{
data: [
{
id: 1,
role: "CRAFT",
template_id: "1",
description: "mtc crafts",
created_at: null,
updated_at: null
},
{
id: 2,
role: "SPR",
template_id: "1",
description: "supervisor",
created_at: null,
updated_at: null
} 
]
}
```

Comment: You don't get any errors? Because this should be working. https://jsfiddle.net/8dg6coox/

Comment: Are you sharing your exact code? Or have you simplified it at all?

Comment: if what you shared is actually `response.data`, you need to using `response.data.data` in your code.

Comment: wha . . .? It works!!  Have I mis-coded something somewhere that requires double 'data'?? Is it because the array is wrapped in data{ . . .} and is there a way to eliminate that?

Comment: You can just return the array itself in the response.

Comment: So in the laravel api controller I had: 
    
    "return response()-> json(['data' => DiloRole::all()]);"

which should have been: 
    
    "return response(DiloRole::all());"

Comment: Can you try using `dilo_roles` as a computed property instead of data()? Typically data is a value that never changes, and must be established up-front:

https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data


"Once observed, you can no longer add reactive properties to the root data object. It is therefore recommended to declare all root-level reactive properties upfront, before creating the instance."

I agree with above that it shouldn't technically matter.

Comment: Issue resolved! On the laravel api side I re-formed the api response as I mention above -  which was inferred by the suggestion of @Brian Glaz . My error was effectively 'double wrapping' laravel's implicit json response.

Comment: I'm using Laravel + Vue + Axios and the double data worked for me also.  I think it's because the request is returning a "collection" with pagination so the "data" was indeed wrapped up a level.  Thanks to @BrianGlaz for pointing this out - I was looking in the wrong place!

Answer (score 0):

So in the laravel api controller I had:

```
"return response()-> json(['data' => DiloRole::all()]);"
```

which should have been:

```
"return response(DiloRole::all());"
```